# Why should it be hard to generalize Dvir's proof of the finite field Kakeya conjecture to the Euclidean case?

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, finite-fields, additive-combinatorics, incidence-geometry

Let $q$ be prime and let
$q\delta \sim 1.$ Let $K$ be any set of $C_n\delta$-separated tubes in $B(0,2)$, where $C_n$ is some constant depending on $n$. Let us consider a grid of $q^n$ points scaled with $\delta^n$. We embed this evenly spaced orthogonal grid in $\mathbf{R}^n$ so that the origins of the two sets meet. Let $K' \subset K$ so that each tube in $K$ contains a line from $K'$. The lines  $a + vt \in K'$ are such that if $v \in tu$ then $a + tu = a + vt$. So that we have $q^{n−1}$ lines in $K$ and the directions are $\delta$-separated (edit: not necessarily true if $K' \subset K$) . By Dvir's theorem we have $\lvert K'\rvert \ge \frac{q^n}{2^n}$. So we have at least that many points $x \in K' \subset K$ that are $\delta$-separated. Multiplying above by $\delta^n$ we have $\lvert K\rvert  \ge \lvert K'\rvert\delta^n \ge q^n\delta^n \frac{1}{2^n} \gtrsim \frac{1}{2^n}$ , because the $C_n\delta$-tubes contain the $\delta$−tubes. Isn't this a straightforward generalization? (EDIT) As was pointed out, those "grid lines" are unlike euclidean lines. The grid lines can go to the end of the grid and then reappear somewhere else in the grid. If a grid line contains $m$ points, it seems to me that for those "grid lines" we may even need  (in euclidean sense) $m$ parallel lines to the cover the grid line. This grows the number of (euclidean) lines and solves the mystery (for me). The solution: Let $K$ contain in addition to $\delta$-separated tubes essentially parallel tubes in order to achieve $K' \subset K.$ However, estimating how many parallel tubes you need may be difficult.

Answer (score 8):

I don't entirely follow your proposed approach, but let me make a few remarks which might help you think about this:

(1) Clearly this can't work, since this argument purports to show that a Kakeya set must have positive Lebesgue measure which, in contrast to the finite field setting, we know is false in Euclidean space.

(2) Note that the discretization of a tube is not necessary an algebraic line or even approximately an algebraic line. Indeed consider R^2 and a tube oriented along the y axis. Now adjust the angle slightly in either direction. What does a discretization of this tube look like? Well it depends on the scales involved but, roughly in the case of a $\delta$ tube rotated by a $~\delta$ degree angle, the discretization will be the union of long segments of vertical lines (rectangles/blocks) stacked on top of each other slowly drifting in the direction of the rotation. This is not an algebraic line.

(3) In the discrete (finite field) setting two lines intersect at a single point. However, for reasons similar to the discussion in (2), two tubes can have substantial overlap. This is sometimes refereed to as "small angle issues" in the literature.

Comment: 1) It does not imply that. It implies that there are infinitely many $\delta$ s.t the tube set is of positive measure. Has anyone showed that tube sets can be formed to make a small Kakeya set? IMO this implies that tubes don`t cover Besicovitch set effectively. 2) The algeibrac lines belong to the tubes. There is that $C_n*\delta$ of room to play.3) Tube intersections don`t matter. It matter that the tubes  contain the points that are $\delta$-separated.

Comment: (1) Consider a $\delta$ neighborhood of a Besicovitch set, then this is a "tube set" with measure decreasing to 0 as $\delta \rightarrow 0$, contradicting the claim you want to prove. (2) Consider the example of a tube rotated by an angle of $\delta$ with the y axis in $R^2$. What algebraic line is contained within it?  (2*) Also think about what a mod p line looks like when plotted under you mapping to $R^n$. It will look like (roughly) an arithmetic progression (with some wrap around) in each variable. Notably it will not be contained within a $\delta$ tube.

Comment: 1) We know it will contain at least $\delta^{1-n}$ tubes and its measure tends to $0$. If the set were to contain more tubes, this would increase the measure not decrease it. 2) What does "$\delta *t (0,1)$ where $t \in F_q$" mean here; $\delta$ is a small real number, not an element of $F_q$?

Comment: 1) Ok. I see , but that does not count as a proof. Please, provide a reference for your technique or make an answer. 2) $\delta*t(0,1)$ where $t \in F_q$. Sorry, I forgot to scale the lines. I was now talking about elements of $R$^n. .3) Why? It is a arithmetic progressin that is rescricted from the continuos line and belongs to a $\delta$-tube.

Comment: (2) the point is that your argument is conflating lines in $R^n$ with lines (arising via your mapping) from $F_p$, and the two are very different. If you don't see this, try to find a line in in $F_p$ contained within a neighborhood of $\delta * t(0,1)$. (3) I suggest you attempt to plot a (discritized) line from $F_p^2$ via your mapping into $R^2$ to see what it looks like.

Comment: Ok. I see what you mean. Why can`t I use $t$ from $F_p$ if the order of the field is $n$, where $p$ is a prime?

Comment: I'll point out Zhang (https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.1352) has developed a variant of Dvir's argument directly in $R^n$ that proves an analog of the Kakeya conjecture where tubes are replaced with Euclidean lines (and points). You can try to insert that into a discretization argument similar to what you are proposing here which will get you around _some_ of the issues we just talked through. But then you start running into things like the "small angle issues" I alluded to with (3). Needless to say it doesn't prove the conjecture. However it might be instructive for you to think through.

Comment: I accept your answer and many thanks for you. Your method 1) seem to work for compact sets. My mistake *) was to estimate the number of lines wrongly. If $(x_1,..,x_n)$ is a point in the grid $[0,1]^n$ we can choose the points in about $q^{n-1}*\Pi(q)$ different ways, where $\Pi(q)$ is the prime counting function. If one of the coordinates is a prime, $0$ or $1$ it generates it`s own line. So we have more than $\delta^{1-n}$ lines in our tube set, so it can`t be $\delta$-separated (I considered only the points where one coordinate is $1$).

Comment: Moreover, most of the algebraic lines will be splitted in two because $a + tv$ will belong to $[0,2q]^n$. So we have essentially two sets. However, even smaller of those  sets contain $\sim q^{n-1}\Pi(q)$ lines. If we can show that we have at least   $\sim q^{n-1}\Pi(q)$ points we have the estimate with an logarithmic factor.

Comment: I don't know how to extend the proof. But those "small angle" issues can be solved by dividing the $\delta$-tubes to really small paraller $\delta'$-tubes, whit small overlap. Then all the angles will be very large compared to $\delta'$.